# Graphql Calling Axios Multiple Calls Performance/Refactoring

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, refactoring, apollo

I'm able to delete and add data into my JSON file, but if I keep pressing the button (toggling add/delete), I get a network failure. I'm assuming that I can't make multiple requests like this?

```
const handleSave = save => {
  if (save.toLowerCase() === 'save') {
    props
      .addSaved({
        variables: {
          id: props.id,
        },
      })
      .then(res => {
        setSaved('Unsave');
        setSavedPropData(res.data.addSaved);
      });
  } else {
    props
      .deleteSaved({
        variables: {
          id: savedPropData.id,
        },
      })
      .then(() => setSaved('Save'));
  }
};
```

The above is the snippet of my handle saving data. So each press it toggle's Save or Unsave, and then it will add or delete data into my JSON. I'm currently using json server to test the application.

```
const savedMutate = gql`
  mutation addSaved($id: String) {
    addSaved(id: $id) {
      id
    }
  }
`;

const deletedMutate = gql`
  mutation deleteSaved($id: String) {
    deleteSaved(id: $id) {
      id
    }
  }
`;

export default _.flowRight(
  graphql(savedMutate, {name: 'addSaved'}),
  graphql(deletedMutate, {name: 'deleteSaved'}),
)(withNavigation(Card));
```

Is there a better way to doing this if I deploy the application into production? Currently I get the network failure when I'm toggling fast. I just tried again, is it because my app refreshes every time and while its refreshing, I'm trying to save into my database, but it hasn't been fully mounted? Is this only happening in development?

mutation:

```
addSaved: {
  type: SavedType,
  args: {
    id: {type: GraphQLString},
  },
  resolve(parentValue, {id}) {
    return axios
      .post(`http://localhost:3000/saved`, {id})
      .then(res => res.data);
  },
},
deleteSaved: {
  type: SavedType,
  args: {
    id: {type: GraphQLString}
  },
  resolve(parentValue, {id}) {
    return axios
      .delete(`http://localhost:3000/saved/${id}`)
      .then(res => res.data);
  },
},
```

Comment: What's the error? You will need a middleware to be able to manage requests and cancel ongoing requests when needed.

Comment: Its more so like a yellow warning saying network failure. I'm noticing that every time I make a request, my nodemon restarts, so my app in development restarts. I'm assuming this Is this the reason, because I'm making requests while its "refreshing" the app. Whats best practices when dealing with simultaneous requests to database? If its in production, will this happen still?

Comment: Well for network failure, check the reason and do a retry if it makes sense. For concurrent requests to a DB, normally there's a middleware managing a "request" or event queue. Then on a larger scale, you will need sharding and replication for your DBs + some fault tolerance mechanism (i.e Byzantine Fault tolerance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running your server with nodemon and you're writing to some file in response to requests and this file is being watched by nodemon, then your requests will always trigger a server restart. Since the first request restarts the server, any requests that follow immediately after will fail because your server will now be down while it is starting back up.

You need to [configure nodemon to ignore the appropriate files or directories](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#ignoring-files). This way, any changes to the files won't cause nodemon to restart your server.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. In production, this won't occur, right? @Joseph D, explained that I would have to find a middleware managing the request.

Comment: If your set-up is identical in production, then yes, it will occur. Presumably, in production (and even in dev) you should be using a database instead of writing to files directly, though, in which case would wouldn't see this behavior unless you had nodemon watching your database directory for some reason.

Comment: Ah, got it! Yeah, I'm going to be writing it to mongodb in production. I'm just using JSON server to architect the app. Thank you for the help!